# how to configure tomcat6 for ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-9.04, jdk

i have installed Apache Tomcat6 for Ubuntu 9.04 recenty.  But it seems that some API's like servelet and http are not included although I have installed OpenJDK 1.6.

Somebody advised me to set JAVA_HOME path variable. But I don't know how or where to make that change. Can someone please explain the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/). and this

I think you've installed jre, jdk and downloaded [tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

Then extract, and move tomcat folder to a permanent location as u like : for example ,

```
sudo mv apache-tomcat-6.0.14 /usr/local/tomcat
```

okay, Tomcat requires setting the JAVA_HOME variable. The best way to do this is to set it in your .[bashrc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html) file. You could also edit your startup.sh file if you so chose.

The better method is editing your .bashrc file and adding the bolded line there. You’ll have to logout of the shell for the change to take effect.

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

At this point you can start tomcat by just executing the startup.sh script in the tomcat/bin folder.